# YouTube Data API issue CommentThreads: Insert Not working

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

YouTube: Data API . CommentThreads: Insert Not working  (Note: To create a top-level comment).

(The comment is visible  ONLY displayed with my own account). If log in with different account then there is no comment)

Following is my JavaScript code :

```js
return gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.insert({
  part: 'snippet',
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      channelId: 'channelId value',
      topLevelComment: {
        snippet: {
          textOriginal: ' Comment Value ',
          videoId: 'videoId value',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: @slidesshowp2 , I try your updated code. But still it is not working. (The comment is visible ONLY displayed if i logged in my own account. If log in with different account then there is comment is NOT visible. ) Thanks

Comment: Same Issue here

Comment: I think the videoId should be in the upper snippet next to channelId